# Button click events intercepted by button content

Tags: javascript, html

I have a pretty basic Bootstrap button on my page.  I have an event listener listening for clicks on this button.  I have an image tag as the content of the button.  When a user clicks the button, the event listener fires as desired.  However, if the button click lands on the image within the button, the image intercepts the click and the button click event listener doesn't fire.  How can I get the button to detect a click on both itself, and its content (e.g. the image tag)?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-custom" id="navLogoButtonLeft">
    <!-- dev tools indicate clicks land on this <img> and never make it to the <button> -->
    <img class="icon" src="img/icon.png">
</button>
```

Note, this is a Twitter Bootstrap button, but I'm not sure that has any bearing on the problem.

Here is the JS, by request.

```
var navLogoButtonLeft;

function initNav() {
    navLogoButtonLeft = document.getElementById('navLogoButtonLeft');

    // note, I've tried both 'true' and 'false' here
    navLogoButtonLeft.addEventListener('click', handleClick, true);
}

// this method does fire, but clickEvent is the <img>, not the <button>
function handleClick(clickEvent) {
    if(clickEvent.target == navLogoButtonLeft) {
        // this line cannot be reached
        window.location = './';
        return;
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', initNav, false);
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please, including your JavaScript

Comment: The JavaScript does not match the HTML. Please read the full content on the page linked to by @j08691.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dev tools are correct. When you click on the image in your button, the event target actually is the image. Nevertheless, the click event should bubble up and finally make the button’s event listener fire.

So, if your HTML is correct (the `//` comments for example would break it), and you correctly added the event listener like

```
var btn = document.querySelector('#navLogoButtonRight');

btn.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
 ev.stopPropagation();
 console.log('Event listener for element ' + ev.currentTarget.nodeName + '#' + ev.currentTarget.id + ' fired.');
 console.log('Clicked on ' + ev.target.nodeName);
});
```

the event listener should fire on click on the button as well as on any of its child elements. `ev.stopPropagation();` in the handler stops the event from bubbling up any further. See a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/quj56hq5/

If you have to set `pointer-events: none;` for this to work, there’s definitely something wrong with your code or some Twitter Bootstrap JS gets in the way.

**Update**

After the JS was added by the question’s author the real cause of the problem showed. It is the line

```
if(clickEvent.targe‌​t == navLogoButtonLeft) {
```

that keeps the handler’s code from being executed when the image is clicked, because `.target` always is the clicked element while `.currentTarget` always is the element the listener was originally attached to.

Comment: Thanks, I'll fix the HTML comments, those were added just for this post.

Comment: .stopPropagation() did not work, but it was worth a try.  The click event on the button object never fires at any time, either before or after the image click is registered.  The click only ever occurs on the image and the button element in the DOM never knows a click happened on it, or on any of its children, unless I make the image (child) unclickable with pointer-events:none

Comment: Note, my code is 100% included, so if something is wrong with it, please let me know what that might be.

Comment: Now that you posted your JS, there show up several things to be fixed. 
a) Your button’s id is `navLogoButtonRight`, but your JS references `#navLogoButtonLeft` but I guess the example just isn’t up-to-date anymore.
b) The real cause of your problem is the line `if(clickEvent.target == navLogoButtonLeft) {` that keeps the code from being executed when the image is clicked, because `.target` always is the clicked element while `.currentTarget` always is the element the listener was originally attached to.

Comment: That did it!  Lots of typos on my part in this post.  Thanks for your persistent effort!

Answer (score 1):

you could just add the same event listener to the image tag to get the desired effect.

Though you could also go to a more technical level
and add a class that sets `pointer-events: none;` in the CSS and add that class to the end of your img tag

Comment: Adding the `pointer-events` CSS did the trick, thanks.  I'm a little worried about compatibility with older browsers, is that an issue?  I'm hoping not to duplicate the listener on more DOM elements if possible.

Comment: from what i read it works in Firefox 3.6+, Chrome 2+, IE 11+, and Safari 4+

Answer (score 0):

Try do the inverse (and using the bubble effect) then try apply the listner to the img (in my sample I simply  change the position of the id associated the listener)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-custom" >
  // dev tools indicate clicks land on this <img> and never make
  //   it to the <button>
   <img class="icon" src="img/icon.png"  id="navLogoButtonRight"   >
</button>
```

Comment: The image doesn't fill the entire button, so what would happen when the button is clicked, but the click doesn't fall on the image?

Comment: @fts_acer   . the bubble effect should progate the effect to the parent ..  .. try and let me know ..or apply the listener at both ..